# parsing "\(|.*?)|)" - Too many )'s

Tags: regex

```
parsing "\(|.*?)|)" - Too many )'s.
```

I am receving this error when writing this...

```
 private static Regex resourceTextsREGEX = new Regex(@"\(|.*?)|)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I want a regular expression for these two things  1- {Text} 2- |Text|   I want to be able to get those matches and replace them with something ...can someone help please?

Comment: You've been using SO for seven months and asked 15 previous questions. With respect, you should be formatting things correctly by now. See the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question edit box, the preview below it, and the **[?]** link above it.

Comment: what is this language and what is "8 hours, 26 minutes ago" in your message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example what you want to match you might have to want something like this

```
[{|](.*?)[|}]
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1qb)

So you want to match
1. {Text}
2. |Text|

My regex is matching at first

`[{|]` either a `{` or a `|`

Then comes a capturing group that gets your text using a lazy match `(.*?)`

And at last the closing character is matched `[|}]` meaning either `}` or `|`

Comment: This pattern will also match "{Text|" and "|Text}".

Answer (score 6):

You haven't said which flavor of regex it is, but the odds are pretty high that `(` and `)` are grouping operators. Your expression has mis-matched parentheses:

```
    @"\(|.*?)|)"
```

You might have meant

```
    @"(|.*?\)|)"
      ^    ^-- escape
      +-- no escape
```

...if you're trying to create a group that may include an actual `)` in it, or

```
    @"\(|.*?\)|\)"
      ^     ^  ^
      +-----+--+--- escapes everywhere
```

...if you're not trying to create a group at all, but just trying to match parens.

Answer (score 2):

you're escaping `(` and not `)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 static Regex resourceTextsREGEX = new Regex(@"({)([^}{\|]+)(})|(\|)([^}{\|]+)(\|)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

this will match `{text}` , `|text|` and **not** with `{}`,`||`,`{text|`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for a regex to match "{some text here}" and "|some text here|".

`(\{.*?\}|\|.*?\|)` should do the trick; it matches anything (with a non-greedy quantifier) inside a pair of curly braces or anything (again non-greedy quantifier) inside a pair of vertical bars, with a pair of grouping parentheses so that you can look at or replace the match.

Of course, if you don't want to match "{}" or "||" you can simply replace each asterisk (*) with a plus (+).