# C# 'parsing ")" - Too Many )'s Issue

Tags: c#

I recently stumbled across this problem while testing my C# program.

> parsing ")" - Too Many )'s

Here is my code:

```
        try
        {
            if (e.ChangedRange.Text.Contains(";") && Convert.ToBoolean(e.ChangedRange.Text.IndexOf(")", 1)))
            {
                if (!e.ChangedRange.Text.Contains(";") && !Convert.ToBoolean(e.ChangedRange.Text.IndexOf(")", 1)))
                    LuaLibrary.isParenthesesSemiColonError = false;
                else
                {
                    LuaLibrary.isParenthesesSemiColonError = true;
                    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(error_red, ");", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

What I'm doing here is, I'm checking to see if the current line (e.ChangedRange.Text) contains ';' with the IndexOf a ')'. (And reversed on the second 'if' statement): I'm assuming they are both causing my issue; however, I don't have a clue on how to fix it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the output, find the formatting error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing "\(|.*?)|)" - Too many )'s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420758/parsing-too-many-s)

Comment: Did the LuaLibrary really spell parentheses as paraentheses? Practicing a little DRY might help.

Comment: @Tod: Can you go off-topic some more?  :::::  Joe: Already looked at it, doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string in your call to `SetStyle` is a regex pattern, so the `)` needs to be escaped.  The problem is that parens are special characters in Regex.  The regex parser is seeing the closing paren, but no opening paren to match it to.

Try this:

```
e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(error_red, @"\);", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I actually did this. A issue tell persists. The if statements won't work when 'Contains' has anything like for example: "^[a-zA-Z]+$" in it.

Comment: @TommyCooper - you don't want `^` and `$` in a regex to test for the existence of a substring

Comment: TextChangedEventArgs e   : Well, either way.. I retested your method, again and I have to type in \); in my editor. Hmm..

Comment: @TommyCooper - So you need to escape the parens in the code above, because the regex parser is seeing a closing paren with no opening paren to match it to.  When you enter code into your editor (the code that is processed by the above event handler) just enter it as normal.

Comment: Thank you! I pretty much got it now. Marking your answer as the best. ;)